# CKEditor loses Curosor position while going to source or html

Tags: ckeditor

How to preserve the cursor position while toggling from/to HTML Source? This is really annoying when you are editing a large article and you want to say fix broken LI (order) or just want to check some HTML.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go [CKEditor Demo page](http://ckeditor.com/demo)
2. Now inside standard editor put your cursor on say last line.
3. Now click the source button, your cursor should be lost and you should be at the top of the HTML source.
4. Now click back on the source button and again this time your cursor will be lost.

As shown in the below GIF when you click on Source it takes you to the top of the HTML and when you click it back it will do the same in the HTML section.

[image: Exmple]